# Variable expansion in JSON object for use with Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell

Over the past few days I've been looking for documentation on variable expansion in JSON objects. I've tried a lot of recommendations and fixes, but none of them seem to work quite as expected. I'm left wondering if there's a better way than I have implemented. Anyway, on to my use case.

**Use Case**
I have an array of integers, which represent objects in a web application. These objects are able to have a relationship established between them by making a POST request to an API endpoint.

This array of integers is referred to as `$combined`.

```bsh
PS C:\> $combined

        i_id       m_id
------------ ----------
       75419       6403
       75420       6403
       75421       6403
       75410       6403
```

To set up the parameters used for my POST request, I've created another array called `$associationParams`.

```bsh
    $associationParams = @{
        ContentType = "application/json"
        Body = '{"id": '+$($thing).m_id+'}'
        Method = "POST"
        URI = "https://application/api/in/$($thing.i_id)/endpoint"
        Headers = $headers
    }
```

The `$headers` variable above is the authorization token.

So, my initial inclination is to loop through the array of integers (`$combined`) and call `Invoke-RestMethod` as so:

```bsh
    Foreach ($thing in $combined) {
        Invoke-RestMethod @iocAssociationParams
    }
```

**Problem**
So, I don't really have a problem per se... There seems to be some inconsistency in my testing where the final `ForEach` doesn't seem to loop through all the elements in the `$combined` array... But I am wondering if there's a better way. I've tried string formatting the JSON object in the Body parameter in `$associationParams`, but it definitely didn't work. I've also tried various forms of quoting, but they didn't work either. Is trying to splat the parameters for `Invoke-RestMethod` the best way? Should I just list out all the parameters for `Invoke-RestMethod` in the `ForEach` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-f` format operator to insert `$thing.m_id` inside the `foreach` into `$AssociationParams`.
You have to escape the literal curly braces by doubling them.

```
Foreach ($thing in $combined) {
    $AssociationParams = @{
        ContentType = "application/json"
        Body        = '{{"id": {0}}}' -f $thing.m_id
        Method      = "POST"
        URI         = "https://application/api/in/$($thing.i_id)/endpoint"
        Headers     = $headers
    }
    Invoke-RestMethod @AssociationParams
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! While it is technically correct, my implemented solution was to cheat by creating a PSCustomObject and then converting it to JSON, rather than deal with variable expansion in a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution as implemented.

```
Foreach ($thing in $combined) {
    # Now we create the body of the request as a Powershell object with the intent to convert it to JSON later
    $AssociationBodyObj = [PSCustomObject]@{
        id = $($thing.id)
    }

    # ...and then we convert it to JSON
    $AssociationBodyObj = $AssociationBodyObj | ConvertTo-Json

    $iocAssociationParams = @{
        ContentType = "application/json"
        Body        = $AssociationBodyObj
        Method      = "POST"
        URI         = "https://application/api/in/$($thing.i_id)/endpoint"
        Headers     = $headers
    }
    Invoke-RestMethod @AssociationParams
}
```